# Print windows form to PDF with controls that use scrollbars? C#

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, printing

Similar question:

[convert windows form to pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813341/convert-windows-form-to-pdf-file)

I am trying to print a Windows form to PDF in a similar manner as the above question, however the method described in that particular answer is essentially taking an image of the form. I have controls that use a scrollbar (e.g. tablelayoutpanel) and need to see all of the information within, rather than whatever selection the scrollbar happens to be on.

Is this possible?

Comment: It is possible because there is a screen capture called "DuckLink" that has the ability to screenshot an entire webpage (with scroll bar), This even has command line support so maybe could even use this

Answer (score 0):

You will need to take a screen shot and use that image to generate a pdf.

The only way I have seen this done is using a program called Snagit, which scrolls the application window automatically whilst capturing it and I assume stitches that together.

I would imagine you would need to do that programatically to get the output you need?

Comment: A quick search reveals: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883308/capture-a-scrolling-window-contents-screenshot

Comment: Yes, the main problem is that a control on my form may have a scrollbar but further controls underneath it. I'd need the capture to essentially "drag" the scrollbar-using control until it no longer needed scrolling

Comment: Figuring that programatically will be tricky. What is the purpose of the screen grab to PDF, if this for reporting, I would suggest formatting a report a different format, ie generate a PDF, Excel, Html or other report using the data.