# C# - Capture screenshot of a full window

Tags: c#, window, scroll, screenshot, capture

Is there a way to capture the entire contents of a window?  Not just the part of the window that is showing but also the part of the window you can only see if you scroll (known as "below the fold")?  Suppose I want to capture the entire contents of a multipage document in notepad in one image.

I've been using the code described in:
http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4630/capture-a-screen-shot/
and
[Capture screenshot of active window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/c-sharp-capture-screenshot-of-active-window)

Using:

```
_processList = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
if (_processList.Length > 0) return _processList[0].MainWindowHandle
```

By getting the window handle of an instance of notepad, I can easily capture the portion of a web page that is *visible*.  But I would like to be able to capture the contents of the entire portion of a scrollable window.  Does such a representation even exist in memory anywhere, or does it only come into being once a window scrolls?

Note: it seems this question has been *asked*, but never really *answered* for anything other than browsers and web pages:
[Capture a scrolling window contents screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883308/capture-a-scrolling-window-contents-screenshot)

Comment: Dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176340/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-a-full-size-window-in-c-sharp